# Disabling garbage collection in Java unexpectedly slows performance

Tags: java

I am trying to examine how Java heap allocations affect overall application performance. To do this, I have created a simple program that creates a large number of objects:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4_000_000; ++i) {
        final Product product = new Product(i);
        sum += product.price();
    }
    System.out.printf("Total: %d\n", sum);
}

private static class Product {
    final String name = new String("Banana");
    final int price;
    private Product(final int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int price() {
        return this.price % 100;
    }
}
```

When I run the program as is, the execution time is around `12.265 ms` (all measurements were made by [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh).) However, because the program creates a large number of objects, I wanted to see how disabling garbage collection would affect performance.

To disable garbage collection I used `EpsilonGC`. So, I've just added the following JVM options:

```bash
-Xmx12294M -Xms12294M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC
```

I then ran the program again, but this time the execution time was unexpectedly slower at `69.188 ms`. I had expected that disabling garbage collection would improve performance, but instead, it seemed to have the opposite effect.

I am confused about why disabling garbage collection leads to such a high execution time. Does the number of objects in memory increase the allocation time for new objects, or is something else happening here? I would greatly appreciate any insights on this issue.

---

Update:

1. [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) microbenchmark code:

```java
public class ProductsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        new Runner(
            new OptionsBuilder()
                .forks(1)
                .warmupIterations(1)
                .measurementIterations(1)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(3))
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(3))
                .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()
        ).run();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void products() {
        Products.main();
    }
}
```

2. System properties:

- Apache Maven 3.9.0
- Java: azul-11 (Java version 11.0.12)
- OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "Mac"
- Available Memory: 16G

Comment: Wouldn’t `product` be eligible for GC at the end of the loop? Maybe disabling GC is forcing higher mem usage and allocations?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If 12G is a tight fit, then there may be some swapping, in which case the performance would go to heck.

Comment: @teapot418 I thought if I have not enough memory I would see `OutOfMemoryError` first?

Comment: @Michael thank you for the comment. Added to the description.

Comment: @DaveNewton probably you right. I think in the same direction, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: A) the allocation in java goes above Xmx B) sum of all currently running programs goes over available RAM C) currently running programs go way over available RAM -> A) OutOfMemoryError B) swapping (slow) C) Operating system notifying you that things are very wrong/killing stuff;; you were wondering about bad performance, my speculation was that you are seeing B

Comment: @teapot418 I decreased the heap size to `-Xmx8196M -Xms8196M` and monitored the swap usage during the test execution. The results showed that the swap usage remained the same as before the test started, and the total used memory in the operating system was less than `10 GB`. The final execution time was `72.051 ms`.